# Firemonkey TNumberBox - new value not available until losing focus

Tags: delphi, focus, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

Using a `TNumberBox` control (at least in Windows, probably other platforms too), when I type in a new value, and then press a button (`TButton`) to save the changes, upon reading the `TNumberBox.Value` property, it's returning the original value before the edit was made. It turns out, this value is not accessible until after the control loses focus.

Now the button used to save changes, I have deliberately disabled its `CanFocus` property, along with all buttons in my app. This is because with the style I use (Jet), a focused button looks horrible (black text on dark gray background). Not to mention, on mobile platforms, focus is practically useless in my case.

Otherwise, if I don't disable `CanFocus` on this save button, the focus is properly taken off of the `TNumberBox` and its `Value` property is okay. But, when disabling `CanFocus` on the save button, the focus is never taken off of this control, and therefore reading its `Value` property returns the old value.

How can I ensure the `Value` property returns the correct new value without changing the save button to `CanFocus`?

Enabling `KillFocusOnReturn` is not useful, because users would have to be aware they need to press "Return" or "Enter" which is not an option.

**NOTE**

This problem also persists if you were to utilize the `TNumberBox.OnChangeTracking` event. I'm not sure how this event would be useful if you can't even read the new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered a dirty work-around at least. Enable the button's `CanFocus` property, then on button click, the very first thing that happens should be setting the focus back to the `TNumberBox` control. That would both allow focus to be taken off of the control (thus refreshing the value), while also taking the focus away from the button (thus avoiding the terrible look).

This however would not be suitable if one were to be utilizing `TNumberBox.OnChangeTracking` and reading the `Value` from within there.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that FireMonkey needs `<ENTER>`, or a loss of focus, to accept a value in any sort of edit.  I don't think you actually need to kill the focus on return.

The real solution to this would seem to be editing the style to change the display of focused buttons.  I didn't like the display of certain controls, or I wanted to add a graphic, etc., so I just went into the style in my project and made changes to get what I wanted.

Comment: That still doesn't help when using `OnChangeTracking` as I say in my answer (although it wasn't part of the question).

Comment: @Jerry Dodge, sorry, it ate my enter (fixed).  From what I can tell from poring through the FM code, edits require an enter or loss of focus to accept a value. If you change the button display, you can cause the loss of focus without the ugly button. I didn't answer your answer about tracking, just the original question.

Comment: Yeah, original question is all that needs to be answered. I'm just waiting and hoping for a more ideal solution because I do intend to utilize `OnChangeTracking` (although this particular scenario doesn't use it).

Comment: @Jerry Dodge, for one project, I had to steal the code for the enter key from FM for use in my form (FM doesn't give you the enter key) and created a key down event that used the enter key before FM gets it. The way it uses keys is very different than VCL in many cases.

Comment: Honestly and unfortunately, I'm in a position where I'm rushed to get at least a version one demo done by a tight deadline, and I don't have time to play Emba's games testing and debugging for them, as that seems to be how their new model has become. "If you want to use Firemonkey, you need to contribute to make it better. Oh, and pay us this and that for us to fix our bugs that shouldn't have been there in the first place." I even saw one Emba dev say "Whoops, sorry." in regards to a mistake in some code they submitted.

Comment: I just tried it and OnChangeTracking returns the previous NumberBox1.Value. But it returns the current proper text with NumberBox1.Text. So you should be able to parse the text to your number.